# How to change the size of a graph using networkx - Big amount of nodes

Tags: python, plot, networkx

I working with graphs on networkx and I am using circular layout to plot it and everything goes well when the amount of nodes is low, but when I add nodes the plot looks ugly and the nodes and edges overlapping.

How can I fix this?

I've thought to make the radio of the circular graph bigger.

My current code is the following:

```html
G=nx.DiGraph()
n=len(C)   
for i in range(n):
    G.add_node(i)
for i in nodos_usuarios:
    for j in nodos_cri:
        if C[i,j]>0:
            G.add_edge(i,j)

    
pos = nx.circular_layout(G)


centro=[0]
nx.draw_networkx_nodes(G, pos, label="ciudades",size=0.1)
nx.draw_networkx_labels(G, pos)
nx.draw_networkx_edges(G, pos, edgelist=edges1, edge_color='green', width=1.7, label="S")
nx.draw_networkx_edges(G, pos, edgelist=edges2, edge_color='black', width=1.7, label="S")
nx.draw_networkx_nodes(G, pos, nodelist=nodos_usuarios, node_color='yellow') 
nx.draw_networkx_nodes(G, pos, nodelist=centro, node_color='blue') 
plt.axes().set_aspect('equal')
plt.xlim(-2,2)
plt.savefig("Red.png")
plt.xticks([])
plt.axis('off')
plt.yticks([])
plt.show()
```

My output is:

[image: Grpah - output]

When I add nodes the graph it looks ugly. How can I improve this?. Thanks and advance.

Comment: Add your image inline, rather than as a link.

Comment: your snippet has the following variables but no definition: 
C, nodos_usuarios, nodos_cri.
What are these variables, please?

Comment: Those are variables whose are used to create the graph. Create and plot the graph is just a part of a bigger work that I am doing.

Comment: OK. I cannot run the snippet to reproduce the problem, because of the missing imports / variables. If I use my own mock variables I cannot guarantee a good solution because of different inputs...

Comment: If you could edit the snippet to include the nominal imports, your own mock variables, and the snippet produces the same problem, it will be much easier to solve and give a useful solution.

Comment: The image with 11 nodes that you linked to looks fine. Can you share the image that you are calling ugly? And what makes it so? Thanks